# Roslyn - Calling ToString on SyntaxNode not preserving precedence

Tags: c#, roslyn

If I create a binary add expression (addExpression) of two int literals like this:

```
BinaryExpressionSyntax addExpression = SyntaxFactory.BinaryExpression(SyntaxKind.AddExpression,
                                            SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression
                                            (SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(10)),
                                            SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression
                                            (SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(100)));
```

. . and then a binary multiply expression, where left is addExpression and right is an int literal

```
BinaryExpressionSyntax multExpression = SyntaxFactory.BinaryExpression(SyntaxKind.MultiplyExpression,
                                         addExpression,
                                         SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression
                                         (SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(5)));
```

Calling `multExpression.ToString()` outputs `10+100*5`. I would expect it to output `(10+100)*5`.
Is this correct behavior?

Comment: I wonder if Roslyn has a way of determining/telling you that the original tree is "invalid". (I.e. it would never be parsed out of a string.)

Comment: It seems like it's that way: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f2b0801f-ccb8-42fd-b910-ef2d5582e8b0/operator-precedence-and-parenthesis?forum=roslyn

Comment: @Rawling I don't think such thing exists... :(

Comment: @Markust It's possible to convert it to string, parse it back from the string, and then call a Roslyn `Equivalent` property, but that "parse it back from a string" step was pretty horrible last time I tried.

Comment: If I use the syntax visualizer add-in for visual studio, '(10 + 100)' is parsed as parenthesized expression.

Comment: A solution would be to create a parenthesized expression for every binary expression, you would end up with pointless parenthesis but it would parse back correctly.

Comment: @Rawling I think you can always retrieve the string representation of the tree. It does not matter if it's "invalid". The Syntax Tree holds everything (that's why they have the 'trivia' thing)  inside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Roslyn Syntax construction API does **not** guarantee that you can only build valid programs.  It is entirely possible to construct a program that will not round-trip through the parser using the factory APIs as you have discovered.

It would be both difficult and expensive to ensure that all constructed trees were round-trippable.  We would need to duplicate all of the logic that is in the parser, as well as spend a lot of time verifying correctness.

Regardng the comment to add parenthesis everywhere.  It is possible to add parenthesis marked with the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Simplification.Simplifier.Annotation` annotation, and then call `Simplifier.Simplify` after construction to remove unnecessary parenthesis.